# xdpi image of ldpi in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have a high quality icon. I copied that to drawable-xdpi folder.  Can I use icon in drawable-xdpi for low density screens without creating drawable-ldpi folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. Do not put that icon in `drawable-ldpi` folder.

If your app runs on `ldpi` device and OS does not found the resources in `drawable-ldpi`. Then it will use resources from `drawable-xhdpi` after scaling.

UPDATE

Quality will not be the same..as it is `ldpi` device.

It will calculate the resolution of new Image like this

resolution of xhdpi icon = x * y
resolution for ldpi will = x/2 * y*2

Comment: So, will there be same quality?

Answer (score 1):

Think it's drawable-xhdpi folder.  Yes, Android will look for drawable in the folder that best fits the display type.  If it is not found, it will try to determine the next best to use.

Comment: So, will there be same quality?

Comment: They will be quite good, but depending on the graphics, you may find you need alternative versions for mdpi ldpi etc. xhdpi→ldpi conversion means scaling 0.375 times (counting in 1D) which can make e.g. «pixel art» to be destructed. However icons designed according to android icon guidelines should not be kind of a pixel art and should not suffer from such scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u put the image in MDPI or just drawable Folder ?

Comment: On hdpi and xhdpi image will get blurry.

Comment: I am doing same. I am putting the High resolution image in mdpi folder and i dont see the image bluring. and if u put the image in xhdpi folder i dont think image would look that crisp and clear in ldpi